# Why is HttpContext.CurrentHandler == TransferRequestHandler and what does that mean?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, httpmodule, httpcontext

while debugging my ASP.NET application i found out, HttpContext.CurrentHandler is set to Handlers.TransferRequestHandler in the first run of HttpModules PreRequestHandlerExecute() function.

I can't find any information on this topic, just putting TransferRequestHandler to google brings up only a few results, lot of them not related to the topic.

Has anybody an explanation what goes on here?

Regards

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/05/26/how-extensionless-urls-are-handled-by-asp-net-v4.aspx

Comment: yes, i found that, too. but it didn't explain properly why TransferRequestHandler is set in the first, and Session-wrapper-handler in the second run... i think, instead of caring about, i'd rather do a test against handler-type and exit the moduel's PreRequestHandlerExecute()